# Doxygen - \sq command

Tags: c++, doxygen

Я изучаю Doxygen. открывая хедеры исходников вижу там строки кода

```
/// Get the current running request.
/// \sq{Type,         Synchronous function,
///     Notification, none (synchronous function)}
```

и их представление в документации

```
Get the current running request. 
 _____________________________________________
| Type          |  Synchronous function       |
| Notification  |  none (synchronous function)|
|_______________|_____________________________|
```

Если пробую сам собрать документацию из исходников  - то вижу строку

```
Get the current running request. \sq{Type, Synchronous function, Notification, none (synchronous function)}
```

Что я делаю не так или какие настройки в файле конфигурации Doxygen нужно изменить

Comment: А теперь на русском.

Comment: I don't speak Russian, so better ask in the English StackOverflow. Furthermore which version of doxygen and what are your setting in the Doxyfile different from the standard settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Я не говорю по-русски, так что лучше спрашивайте в английском StackOverflow. Кроме того, какая версия doxygen и какие настройки в Doxyfile отличаются от стандартных (doxygen -x Doxyfile)?

Comment: вопрос решен https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067521/doxygen-command/68067900#68067900
закройте плиз здесь,
нет смысла писать на Ru ресурсе - тут пользователи с китайскими каракулями в имени, советуют писать на русском,
а на англ язычном ресурсе пользователи дают ответы а не советы ...
извините за каламбур ...